# Time Out Exception On WCF Callback

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, service

I do not know Why I am recieving a TimeOutException in my code:

```
    Dim Uri2 As New Uri("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ssWcfService/Service1/")
    Dim binding2 As New WSDualHttpBinding()

    Dim callback = New MyCallBackClient()

    Dim Client = New MyContractClient(callback, binding2, New EndpointAddress(Uri2))

    'Dim Proxy = Client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()
    Dim ProxyNotFaulty = Client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()

    Try
        Dim dataList As New List(Of DataClass)
        Dim datas As New DataClass

        RichTextBox.Text = "Connecting to WCF Service..."
        RichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Please Wait..."

        RichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Please Wait..."
        RichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "The Operation is now Invoking..."

        ProxyNotFaulty.DoSomething()

        For Each Clientdata As DataClass In dataList
            RichTextBox.Text += "The CallBack Status" + Clientdata.callbackMessage
            RichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine
            RichTextBox.Text += "After CallBack Status" + Clientdata.OnCallBackMessage
        Next Clientdata
        Client.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An Exception Happened:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Client.Abort()
    Finally
    End Try
```

---

```
Sub DoSomething() Implements IService1.DoSomething
    data.callbackMessage = "Call Back is Made SuccessFully From Client To Service"
    data.OnCallBackMessage = "Null"
    dataList.Add(data)
    Dim callBack = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel(Of IIIService1)()
    callBack.OnCallBack()
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub DoSomething()

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub DoSomethingTwo()

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetStatus() As List(Of DataClass)


    '<OperationContract()>
    'Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    '<OperationContract()>
    'Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType

    ' TODO: Add your service operations here

End Interface
```

---

```
Public Interface IIIService1

    <OperationContract(IsOneWay:=True)>
    Sub OnCallBack()

    <OperationContract(IsOneWay:=True)>
    Sub OnCallBackFromService()


End Interface
```

Comment: Why do you create ProxyNotFaulty Channel if you have Client object? And what method exactly causes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Is it reaching your service? Have you used Fiddler to see what is going on with communication? Use visual studio to attach to your service (self hosted) or attach to IIS (hosting under IIS) and set a break point on a entrypoint and see what's going on there.

It's possible that

1. It isn't getting to your service
2. Your service is taking too long and is timing out